# Keras model compilation settings (view/change)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have the following Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(
   loss      = CategoricalCrossentropy(label_smoothing=0.01),
   optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.0)
   metrics   = [Accuracy()]
)
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I view compilation settings (like the learning_rate)?
2. How can I change compilation settings (like the learning_rate)?

Remarks:

- I noticed I can view layer settings using model.summary() or model.get_config() but that does not show compilation settings.
- I know I can change the learning_rate by running the compile statement again with a different learning_rate. But I would like a "cleaner"/ more readable way to do this. Something like: `model['compilation']['optimizer']['learning_rate'] = xxx`. (Many sklearn model can be adjusted this way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.lr`:

```
rate = model.optimizer.lr
```

Comment: Thanks. Small addition: float(model.optimizer.lr) returns the learning rate as a float.